# Why I need 'show.html.erb' template for going to '.../posts/index'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make my first Ror app and here is my first problem :)

When I go to localhost:3000/posts/index, I get message 'Missing template posts/show, application/show with {:locale...' Why is that? Why I need show.html.erb template for posts/index?

`routes.rb` file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root 'posts#index'
end
```

Routes after `$rake routes` command:

```
   Prefix Verb    URI Pattern            Controller#Action
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
     root GET    /                         posts#index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect your routes you'l will notice that the posts#index action is mapped to /posts, not posts/index.

What's happening here is that /posts/index is getting mappend to /posts/:id, with index being set as the id. With a GET request this gets mapped to the show action.